# Referencing previously defined items in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I'm trying to wrap my head around defining JSON-LD correctly for my website. The bit I'm not sure about is how to reference previously defined JSON-LD items without having to copy and paste them.

I know that each item can be given an `@id` property, but how should I correctly utilize it (if I even can)?

For example, suppose I create an `Organization` item with an `@id` of `https://example.com/#Organization`.
When I need to reference that item again, is it correct to simply specify that `@id` again, nothing more?

Also am I correct in assuming that I can do this even if the item isn't defined on the page that I'm referencing it?

In the case of the `Organization` item type, my understanding is that you should only declare it on the home page, rather than every page, so if the user is currently on the product page, and I want to reference the organization, it isn't already defined on the page I'm on, but has been declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that using the same `@id` in different places allows you to make statements about the same thing. In fact, the JSON-LD [Flattening](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#flattened-document-form) algorithm, which is used as part of [Framing](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#framed-document-form), consolidates these all together in a single node object.

JSON-LD is a format for Linked Data, and it is reasonable to say that statements made about the same resource on different locations (pages) can be merged together, and if you form a Knowledge Graph from information across multiple locations, this is effectively what you're doing. A Knowledge Graph will typically reduce the JSON-LD (or other equivalent syntactic representation) to [RDF Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#dfn-triple)/Quads, where each "page" effectively defines a graph, which can be combined to create a larger [Dataset](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#dfn-dataset). You can then query the dataset in different ways to retrieve that information, which can result in the separate statements being consolidated.

Most applications, however, will likely look for a complete definition of a resource in a single location. But for something like Organization, you could imaging that different Employee resources might be made, where there is a relation such as `:Employee :worksFor :Organization`, so that the page for an Organization would not expect to also list every employee in that organization, but a more comprehensive Knowledge Graph made from the merge of all of those separate resources could be used to reconstruct it.